# Excel Formula Multiplying based on cells that are filled in?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I was hoping that someone knows a formula for what I want to do. I want to have the F&B per group room night (Budget) to calculate based on the room nights (Row 8) multiplied by the F&B budget (Row 9). but the kicker is that I need a formula that would do the calculation no matter where I put in the room nights.

For example, the formula would work if I put 400 in June and will still work if I put it in September and without changing the formula.

Is this even possible???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`SUMPRODUCT` is likely your best bet here.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B8:M8,B9:M9)
```

This will return `(B8*B9 + C8*C9 + ... + M8*M9)` treating any blanks as zero, giving you the total cost.